# Drupal: Create Content Link Missing in Admin Menu

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

The Create content link in my admin menu is missing. Any ideas ?

**Update**: I am using Drupal 6.17 and the admin account. Previously I was using the 6.x-1.5 version of the admin menu. I updated to the 6.x-3.0-alpha4 to see if the problem was solved but nothing changed.

[alt text http://img834.imageshack.us/img834/670/screenshotp.png](http://img834.imageshack.us/img834/670/screenshotp.png)

Comment: May you attach a screenshot, to allow to understand better to which link you are referring? If you are referring to the "Create content" link (http://img.skitch.com/20100720-puapdp1k49nx1kg24r3u71n8hf.png), then it's not in the admin menu.

Comment: Are you accessing the site using the Drupal super user account?

Comment: kiamlaluno, yes I am using the super user account.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. 
When I looked under my navigation menu: /admin/build/menu-customize/navigation
I realized that the 'Create Content' link was not nested under the 'Administer' menu. 
After I re-arranged the menu items:

```
 - Administer
  - Create Content
```

I refreshed the Admin menu cache; here: /admin/settings/admin_menu/flush-cache/admin_menu or by clicking "Wipe and rebuild" from the Admin Menu Settings page.

Answer (score 1):

Create content is not in the admin tab:

You have 4 tabs standard:

-Create content

-My account

-switch theme

-administer

Create content is the first (but it falls outside your screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the admin_menu cache by visiting example.com/admin_menu/flush-cache/admin_menu. If that doesn't help, see if http://drupal.org/node/502500 does.

Comment: Marcvangend, I tried that but cleaning the cache didn't work and there are more people with the same problem http://drupal.org/node/502500#comment-3213750.

Comment: I just tried this to get the Create Content list to update (wasn't displaying recently created nodes) and now I have the same issue as Joao: missing Create Content link.  Doh!

Answer (score 0):

Permissions? You could conceivably have access to admin menu but not be able to add any content.

Comment: Jeremy, I am using the admin account.